# How to show last post of each website of a MU wordpress in HomePage

Tags: posts, multisite, homepage, settings-api

I'm running a Wordpress MU website and each website has its own "life" but now I would like to show last X posts of each blog of my network on the homepage.

I know how to do it using Feeds and a plugin named FeedPress but this is a "dirty" way to do it. Is there anyone who knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already got a solution that works using FeedPress you might as well stay with that, there isn't a particularly clean way of aggregating multisite posts into a single blog.

One alternative is to use the [Sitewide Tags plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/), but given what you want to do, you should probably stay with what's working.

Comment: Using FeedPress and RSS feeds is an easy solution but it also uses a lot of resources, a few months ago I tested this plugin because I wanted to create a news aggregator but adding 8/9 feeds (with more then 50 daily posts each) increased my server load so much that I had to close the news aggregator due to a lack of performance, this is the reason why I'm trying a different solution like query_post but between different blogs inside the same Wordpress MS installation.

Comment: Do you mean FeedWordPress? I've used that without experiencing heavy load. But if that's a concern then try the Sitewide tags plugin I mentioned in my answer

Comment: ops, yes, FeedWordpress :-) Ok, I'll try thank you very much for you patience!
Anyway I'm still open to new solutions, I love to learn new stuff.